# Is there an accessible table or enum of default types somewhere inside Lua?

Tags: types, lua, typechecking

Does Lua store its default types somewhere and can they be accessed? Either through Lua directly or via C API? I know about the function `type()`, but is it possible to, for example, iterate through these types? If there is no such table, is there at least a way to check if a passed string is a default type that can be returned by the forementioned function? I assume that since Lua can recognize its types, it stores them somewhere, but can they be accessed somehow? Yes I know that I can make my own type table, the problem is that I will need this table both in Lua and C and this way it *will* get messy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an array in [the Lua source code](https://www.lua.org/source/5.4/ltm.c.html#luaT_typenames_) that `type` uses:

```c
static const char udatatypename[] = "userdata";

LUAI_DDEF const char *const luaT_typenames_[LUA_TOTALTYPES] = {
  "no value",
  "nil", "boolean", udatatypename, "number",
  "string", "table", "function", udatatypename, "thread",
  "upvalue", "proto" /* these last cases are used for tests only */
};
```

But that's an implementation detail, not part of the public API, and it contains a few values that you won't actually ever get from calling the function. [The documentation for `type`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-type) says:

> The possible results of this function are "`nil`" (a string, not the value **nil**), "`number`", "`string`", "`boolean`", "`table`", "`function`", "`thread`", and "`userdata`".

If I were you, I'd just hardcode that type table in one place in your program.

Comment: Yes, this part with additional types is ruining the whole idea. Its kinda what I was expecting. It is present in Lua, but I shouldn't use it. Thank you, I will write my own list.